# Switching fragment UI's not removing the last fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm trying to switch fragments with an ontouchlistener set on the entire screen. I've done a lot of googling about how to switch fragment UIs, and thisseems to be the general answer; however, when I use this method it doesn't do anything except adds a somewhat transparent version of the fragment I want below my current UI, and then for some reason when I click on that fragment it takes me out of my current activity and goes to my last activity which is weird because I never added an attempt.

```
public class suggestedfriends extends Fragment{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestedfriends,
            container, false);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Fragment newFragment = new profile();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.mainfragment, newFragment);


                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
      }




 }
```

this is the code I'm using for my fragment and here's the code for the fragment I'm creating:

```
public class profile extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment,
            container, false);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Fragment newFragment = new search();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.mainfragment, newFragment);


                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
        return view;
      }
}
```

this is a really weird problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of new search(); shouldnt you call new suggestedfriends()

Comment: Well my current fragment  is suggested friends()  and I want to switch to profile() so how would I do that by creating a new suggested friends?